# mongoDB and streaming data - how to get latest results?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm making a mongoDB (with pymongo) which is constantly being filled with date-sensitive data. I'd like to retrieve this data, but making sure it's always the freshest data I'm getting.

With `.find()` I should be able to do this, right?

Also, should I index the db?

As for efficiency, would ten thousand concurrent connections to a mongodb be a problem?

Any small advice much appreciated!

Comment: Just as a sidenote: You are asking three relatively independent questions, consider narrowing your scope the next time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mongo cursor is infact a stream from the DB so as you assume doing:

```
find({}).sort({date: -1})
```

Will get a stream of newest records. There is a problem with timeouts here. If you were to use this as a pubsub function you are better off using tailable cursors etc.

You should always index the field. No question there since you are querying on the field by applying a sort to it.

> As for efficiency, would ten thousand concurrent connections to a mongodb be a problem?

This last line is extremely subjective. I am unsure how I can answer this without knowing your document, expected index size, working set size, server setup and a whole tonne of other things.

Comment: Great, thank you! Though, how do you handle the db stream? Can you handle it by each item coming back from it as a stream?

Comment: @KnutOle each time you pick an item out oin a for loop or whatever it is taken directly from the stream with each item being a document. So each iteration actually calls the cursor on server side (in mongo) and takes a result from the top.

Comment: "Will get a stream of newest records." Records since when? And how often should I index the db?

Comment: @KnutOle You should index the collection when you create it. MongoDB will handle any indexing post creation of the index using `ensureIndex`. As I said the cursor is a stream so theoretically each time you query it will get the latest record since the start of the iteration of the loop whether it be 1st time or 100th time around the loop.

Comment: Thanks! Last question: Is there a way to get all the last records since last call (not in a loop)?

Comment: @KnutOle Since you are searching in reverse order you could get the very first _id you find and use a query like `find(_id:{$gt: last_id}).sort({date: -1})` that should be able to do it.